# Android Enumeration

Tags: android, enumeration

Can Android enumerate a USB Plug-and-Play device. The standard enumeration using the API does not seem to work. I am using an OTG cable.
Does anyone have an example on how to do it. The code I am using is very simple:

In onCreate() I have:

usbManager = (UsbManager)getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);

In onClick() I have (there is a button on the screen):

Map usbDeviceList = sbManager.getDeviceList();
Toast.makeText(this, String.format("Number of devices = %d", usbDeviceList.size()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

This works if I plug a memory stick into the OTG cable. It also works if I plug a USB device that I created. It does not work with a bought barcode scanner.

Comment: show us your code. maybe it has errors

Comment: I showed the code in a question I asked on Sep 19.  In onCreate() I have:

usbManager = (UsbManager)getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);   In onClick() I have (there is a button on the screen):

Map<String, UsbDevice> usbDeviceList = sbManager.getDeviceList();
Toast.makeText(this, String.format("Number of devices = %d", usbDeviceList.size()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); The strange thing is that I have a USB device that I created using a Freescale JM60 and it enumerates just fine with this code. When I plug a purchased barcode scanner (which is USB PNP) it does not work.

Comment: dont comment your question! use edit